# scripting in awk

Tags: awk, unix

I have a text file with contents as below:

```
1,A,100
2,A,200
3,B,150
4,B,100
5,B,250
```

i need the output as :

```
A,300
B,500
```

the logic here is sum of all the 3rd fields whose 2nd field is A and in the same way for B

how could we do it using awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a `hash` as:

```
awk -F"," '{cnt[$2]+=$3}END{for (x in cnt){printf "%s,%d\n",x,cnt[x]}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not up for writing and debugging the code for you. However, the elements you need are:

- You can use [`FS=","`](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Field-Separators.html#Field-Separators) to change the field separator to a comma.
- The fields you care about are obviously the second (`$2`) and third (`$3`) fields.
- You can create your own [variables](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Using-Variables.html#Using-Variables) to accumulate the values into.

  - I'd suggest an [associative array variable](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Array-Intro.html#Array-Intro), indexed by field two.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F"," '{_[$2]+=$3}END{for(i in _)print i,_[i]}' OFS="," file
A,300
B,500
```